# Performance Testing of OBIEE application?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, loadrunner, obiee

---

Following parameters should be set for OBIEE Presentation Server only during load testing.
OBIPS\instanceconfig.xml
save and exit file Restart OBIEE processes using OBIEE EM console.

```
<ServerInstance>
        [...]

<Cursors>

<NewCursorWaitSeconds>36000</NewCursorWaitSeconds>

<OldCursorWaitSeconds>36000</OldCursorWaitSeconds>

</Cursors>

[...]

</ServerInstance>
```

Comment: Is that a question or are you just posting random instanceconfig snippets?

Comment: Its an answer.. this value will prevent to re sending the request after every 20 sec which is useful only when doing performance testing

Answer (score 0):

You do know that this represents a value of 10 hours, correct?   You are willing to lock resources for that length of time?   This is counterintuitive for optimal application performance as you would seek to recover resources as fast as possible to support more sessions versus locking a resource for an extended period of time.

I refer to the following performance "compass rose" as a guiding item (independent of tool)

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you need to amend the file on a remote server you can do this either via [OS Process Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler) or via [SSH Command Sampler](https://github.com/yciabaud/jmeter-ssh-sampler#ssh-command). The first one is a part of JMeter installation, the second one you can install using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

See [How to Run External Commands and Programs Locally and Remotely from JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter) for more information, example configuration and sample commands.